# How I change query onclick combobox event in php?

Tags: php, mysql, combobox

I am new with php.I want to change query when some event occur on ComboBox. So that according to that query I retrieve data from database in php.The code is given below:-

```
 <form method="POST" action="">
                        <select id="choose-color">
                            <option value="all">All</option>
                            <option value="blue">Blue</option>
                            <option  value="black">Black</option>
                            <option value="white">White</option>
                        </select>
  </form>
 <?php
            $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","123");
            mysqli_select_db($conn,"DwtCW");
            $q = "Select * from Clothes";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $q);
            if (!$result) {
                echo 'Some error';
            }
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
              if($row{'Image_url'} != ''){
                  echo '<div>'
                                   . '<img src='.$row{'Image_url'}.'/>'
                        .'</div>'
            }
```

?>

When I select blue option of ComboBox my $q(query given in above code) is change to

```
$q = "Select * from Clothes where colour = 'blue'";
```

So there should appear only images of clothes  having blue colour onpage.

How I reach it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to send ajax request to PHP page. onChange event will trigger ajax request and will change query.

```
 <form method="POST" action="">
                        <select id="choose-color">
                            <option value="all">All</option>
                            <option value="blue">Blue</option>
                            <option  value="black">Black</option>
                            <option value="white">White</option>
                        </select>
  </form>


 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function(){
       $('#choose-color').on('change', function(){
        var color = $(this).val();
        if(color){

        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "index.php",  //or your php page
          data: { color: color }
        })
          .done(function( msg ) {
            alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        });
    }
      });
    });
     </script>
       <?php
            $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","123");
            mysqli_select_db($conn,"DwtCW");

              $whr =  ' ';
```

// check if color is posted on change event

```
         if ( isset($_GET['color'] ) ) {

               $whr .= " where  colour = '".$color."' ";


              }

              $q = "Select * from Clothes $whr";

             $result = mysqli_query($conn, $q);
             if (!$result) {
                echo 'Some error';
              }

           while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
             if($row{'Image_url'} == ''){
                 echo '<div>'
                               . '<img src='.$row{'Image_url'}.'/>'
                    .'</div>'
           }

          ?>
```

Comment: Ajax code return me the whole html page of index.php but inside the if(isset()) method , it not prompt echo or anything. Why?

Comment: url need to be the script page and you need to echo the result and use it inside you hTML

Comment: I understand the first one code and its prompt the msg but When I check color is posted or not , it's not working , Plese guide me how I know that the color is change in php?

Comment: ok to check color is posted or not you need to check Firebug and Net menu in firefox. it will show you the posted data. I hope you know about this. Please let me know in case of issue

Comment: When I write in $("#myDivId").html(msg) , its works fine. Thank you for your helping.